# github, how to search issues I posted or commented

Tags: search, github

github only list top several issues I posted or commented, so I'm wondering how to search for the rest of them myself, of all issues that I myself ***participated***.

Comment: Why isn't navigating to https://github.com/issues not good enough?

Comment: Ah, that simple. sure.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I achieved this by putting `is:issue involves:my-username` in GitHub search.

This chapter from official docs can be really helpful [GitHub Help: Searching issues and pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/).

Comment: Yep, it works as I wanted, sorry @Nikhita this ***is*** answer.

Comment: FWIW, I just tried issuing the `is:issue involves:my-username` in GitHub Community, where I posted a question a week ago. It didn't find it. Instead it reported, "There are no discussions here yet".

Comment: Can I edit this to use `involves:@me` instead? It makes the snippet copy/pastable without needing to substitute `my-username`

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an officially supported way to do that yet. See issue: https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/283.

However, in the [Notification Settings](https://github.com/settings/notifications), there is an option called "Include your own updates" which is unchecked by default.

If you check that, Github will send you an email for every comment/PR you make. Now you can use appropriate email filters/labels to make sure it doesn't clutter your email. Then searching for the issue you commented reduces to a problem of searching your email, which if done correctly, is much efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Converting my comment to an answer - once you're logged in, navigating to https://github.com/issues will show all your issues (categorized to open and closed ones).

Comment: Oh, wait, found that the issues I commented on are not in that list. So how to search for issues I **both** posted or commented?